# Why does unlink(1) support only one file?

Tags: command-line, coreutils

I'm used to commands supporting multiple filename arguments if possible, but `unlink` doesn't:

```
%> unlink a b
unlink: extra operand `b'
Try `unlink --help' for more information.
```

I ended up using a `for` loop. Is there a technical reason why `unlink` only takes one filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unlink(1)` is an intentionally simplified variant of `rm(1)`.

I'm not certain why it was created, but it's probably due to the fact that under the hood, `rm(1)` is implemented in terms of the `unlink(2)` system call. Therefore, I assume the reason for `unlink(1)` is to provide a more direct path to the system call. Someone doubtless came up with a use case where `rm(1)` did the wrong thing and decided the best way to fix it was to provide this direct path.